# Configuration file in U-boot

Tags: u-boot

Is there any config file in U-boot similar to config files(in arch/arm/configs/ for ARM) in Linux.

My doubht here is, while building U-boot it is taking CPUDIR(in the top Makefile) as "arch/arm/cpu/armv7". I am trying to understand from where it is taking the configuration as "arm" and "armv7".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the header files in include/configs are what you're looking for. You'll need to determine which file is used for your board.

From http://www.stlinux.com/u-boot/modifying:

> **Configuration files**
>
> The important configuration information for U-Boot is defined in the file:

```
    include/configs/<board>.h
```

> For example, the Espresso board default configuration file is:

```
    include/configs/espresso.h
```

Comment: It seems, it is taking from boards.cfg file exists in the top directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you see the U-Boot tree on the directory

/configs

you will have the board default configuration files.